# problem with messages

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I got a message from my bf on my iphone and could reply as normal, but when I sent a picture, a new thread was added in my inbox. The same thing happened when I deleted both of the threads and wrote a new message. The one I sent was there and when he replied, another thread was suddenly in the inbox. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

When you open your Pictures app, select the picture you would like to send, and then select send in an email, it doesn't know that it "should" be part of the previous thread. It is a new email. If it was added to the thread, then technically, any email that you send to him should part of the same thread. Unfortunately, even if you type the same Subject in as the thread, it will still not show in that thread.

Comment: There is a work around though, if it is important that you have it in the same thread. Open Pictures and prepare the image to send as you normally would. Before sending it, hold your finger on the image. Copy should be one of the options that appears. Select that, cancel the draft, select reply to the thread, and hold you finger down there - several options should appear - one of which is Paste.

Comment: ok..Thanks for the info. Do you know why a new thread starts even if I send a regular message? I mean, I send him the message, but when he replies, the message is shown in a new thread..

Comment: In order for a thread to continue, both the sender, and recipient must click reply. Otherwise, I don't know. Some email clients seem to do that. Please don't forget to mark my answer if it answered your question.

Comment: We both click reply, so I'm not sure why this is happening. But thanks anyway!